# Power BI Dataflow - Sharepoint Folder Credential Error

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I am connecting to a sharepoint folder using Dataflow, I have managed to load the relevant files, however when I try to exand the binary content I get the following error : "We could not evaluate this query due to invalid or missing credentials."

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Efk.png)

Do my credentials need to updated in the guest tenant to change this?